# PHP not writing to file even though there are no errors

Tags: php, file-io

I have the following script that is supposed to take the input from two forms and then rewrite two different files with the input from the forms. When I put in text into the forms and run it I get no errors but neither of the files were changed at all. I have all the proper permissions set and correct file paths. I changed the paths in the code below so as not to show sensitive information to my server. I'm really scratching my head at this one since php is a fairly new language to me so any help is greatly appreciated.

HTML Code

```
<form name="editfront" action="save.php" method="post">
    <div class="editareasmall">
        <textarea rows="1" cols="150" id="title" name="title"></textarea>
        <script>$('#title').load('../content/front/Title');</script>
    </div>
    <div class="contentheader">Content</div>
    <div class="editareabig">
        <textarea rows="30" cols="150" id="content" name="content"></textarea>
        <script>$('#content').load('../content/front/Content');</script>
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value=" Save " class="save">
</form>
```

PHP Code

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', true);

$title = $_POST['title'];
$content = $_POST['content'];
$filenametitle = "../content/front/Title";
$filenamecontent = "../content/front/Content";

echo 'Form data has been saved';
$filetitle = fopen($filenametitle, "w") or die("can't open file");
$filecontent = fopen($filenamecontent, "w") or die("can't open file");
fwrite($filetitle,$title);
fwrite($filecontent,$content);
fclose($filetitle);
fclose($filecontent);
?>
```

Comment: `if( fwrite($filetitle,$title) === FALSE ) echo "unable to write to the file $filetitle"` Check to see if writing to the file fails.

Comment: Other suggestions, check to see `file_exists($filetitle)` just to be on the safe side, I know you said it does, but checking the script logic.

Comment: `file_exists($filetitle)` returns 1 and the conditional gets a warning. `Warning: fwrite(): 2 is not a valid stream resource`. and then it writes `unable to write to the file Resource id #2`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you submit the form, do you get your output message?

> "Form data has been saved"

Comment: It works on my end too. did you change anything or did it just work without any modificaton? I can't see the php

Comment: Your a genius! I've spent the last 3 hours trying to figure that out. It works perfectly thank you.

Comment: Happy to help! I'd have a play around with that until you get it doing exactly what you want though, I imagine you don't want all your scripts ' resources running in their own little directories..

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that in php multi file opening is available?
Change your error reporting to -1. You will be informed about notice error.

Comment: Changed it to negative one and I didn't see any new output at all nor did any of the files get edited.